# Cognos 8.3: Can I use parameters in conditional style expressions?

Tags: cognos

I have Start Date and End date parameters that work fine as filters on a query, as follows:

```
[EMR Reporting].[Appointments].[Appointment Date] between ?Start Date? and ?End Date?
```

But when I attempt to apply conditional styles to a field based on ?Start Date?, the report blows up.

Should I be able to use parameter values in conditional style expressions, or is this not supported for some reason?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on "blows up"?

Comment: yes ... an error msg would help.  and yes you are able to use parameter values in conditional styel expressions.

Answer (score 1):

what you look like you are doing seems sound.

create a boolean variable... with the condition of `[EMR Reporting].[Appointments].[Appointment Date] between ?Start Date? and ?End Date?`

then use it as as style variable or something when true...   this all should work.  more details may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Create a new query and feed a query item with the parameter value.
Then, associate the report page to the query you just created and try formatting conditionally. I haven't tried this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late
Add a dataitem with the parameter value to your current query. Add it to your report item. Hide the column. Use it in your conditional formatting expression